# php xml iterator

Tags: php, xml

I have the following xml:

```
<user>
    <section xmlns="ss">Testing</section>
    <department xmlns="da">IT</department>
</user>
```

Now while iterating, i want the namespace information for the tag(ss for section and da for department).

With SimpleXMLIterator, I am not able to get the namespace info for every tag.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: for a start that's not XML :)

Comment: why whats the issue with it....

Comment: @Brian Sure looks like valid XML to me.  All elements have a close, there's a single root element, and there are no invalid characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`SimpleXMLElement::getNamespaces()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.getnamespaces) method to access the element's namespace(s).

```
$xml = '
<user>
    <section xmlns="ss">Testing</section>
    <department xmlns="da">IT</department>
</user>
';

$iterator = new SimpleXMLIterator($xml);
foreach ($iterator as $element) {
    var_dump($element->getNamespaces());
}
```

Outputs (along with lots of warnings because of your broken XML):

```
array(1) {
  [""]=>
  string(6) "ss"
}
array(1) {
  [""]=>
  string(6) "da"
}
```